# How to create a dropdown list in ODOO?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo

I find it uncomfortable to use many to one:

```xml
<record id="view_order_form_customize" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.form.customize</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"></field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="partner_id" position="after">
            <field name="area"/>
        </field>
        <field name="area" position="after">
            <field name="subarea"/>
        </field>
        <field name="subarea" position="after">
            <field name="district"/>
        </field>
        <field name="date_order" position="after">
            <field name="scheduleddate"/>
        </field>
        <field name="scheduleddate" position="after">
            <field name="courierid"/> 
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

Could anyone help me adding those in dropdown list for odoo7?

Comment: If you create a `many2one` field, and you add it to the XML view, you will see a dropdown list. What do you want to know? How to create a `many2one` field in OpenERP7?

Comment: This link refer http://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/default-value-many2one-in-odoo-8/ this link work on openERP7. and what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For who are all responsed my questions. first am new to ODOO. i found to use SELECTION field type for ODOO. and i wrote it in python and very sorry to show xml view in question.

```
def _get_selection(self, cursor, user_id, context=None):
  return (('choice1', 'ABT'), ('choice2', 'KPN'), ('choice3', 'FREE Courier'))
```

_columns = {'couriercompany': fields.selection(_get_selection, 'Courier Company', size=16, required=True),}